# Java enum, different value depending on bool value

Tags: java, enums

I want to create an enum class, lets say:

```
public enum runtimeStatus {
    STATUS1("passed"),
    STATUS2("failed"),
    STATUS3("notrun");

    private String status;

    private runtimeStatus(String statusCode) {
            status = statusCode;

    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Okay, I'm accesing those properties with `runtimeStatus.STATUS1.getStatus();` 
But how can I accomplish to pass a boolean to that call, so I get a different output. Lets say for STATUS1 if passed boolean is TRUE to return "passed" if its FALSE to return "passed-type2"

Comment: Write method like `getStatus(boolean status)` and return different enum value depending on `status` value

Comment: add a boolean variable `subtype` to your enum class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below way. We can define as many number of fields in enum and have logics in enum methods.

```
public enum runtimeStatus
{
    STATUS1("passed", "passedType2"), 
    STATUS2("failed", "failedType2"), 
    STATUS3("notrun", "notRunType2");

    private String statusTrue;

    private String statusFalse;

    private runtimeStatus(String statusTrueCode, String statusFalseCode)
    {
        this.statusTrue = statusTrueCode;
        this.statusFalse = statusFalseCode;

    }

    public String getStatus(boolean value)
    {
        return (value == true) ? statusTrue : statusFalse;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish. Thank you, and thanks everyone else for their suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Overload your getStatus method.

```
public String getStatus(boolean statusType) {
    if (statusType) {
        return getStatus();
    }
    return "passed-type2";
}

public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following method to Your existing `enum` :

```
  public String getStatus(boolean passed) {
    if(passed) {
      return STATUS1.getStatus();
    }else {
      return STATUS2.getStatus();
    }        
  }
```